# How to make button fill table cell

Tags: html

I have this HTML ...

```
<p align='center'>
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td align='center'><form><input type=submit value="click me"></form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
```

... which results in a table and button that looks like this ...

[image: button that does not fill table]

... which is fine, but how would I make the button fill the entire cell?

Thanks!

Comment: check this out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989859/css-inline-element-stretch-to-fill-available-horizontal-space-of-container>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For starters:

```
<p align='center'>
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td align='center'><form><input type=submit value="click me" style="width:100%"></form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
```

Note, if the width of the input button is 100%, you wont need the attribute "align='center'" anymore.

This would be the optimal solution:

```
<p align='center'>
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td><form><input type=submit value="click me" style="width:100%"></form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would I need height:100% also ? if so would I use this: style="width:100%;height:100%" ?

Comment: You would only need to do that if the height of your <td> element is greater than the height of the <input> element. You could definately do that.